# DNF for (P<->Q)&&(Q<->R)

Tags: math, boolean-logic, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to write the preposition `(P<->Q)^(Q<->R)` in disjunctive normal form. So far I got `((p^~q)v(q^~p)) ^ ((q^~p)v(p^~q))`, and I'm stuck here. I wonder what would be my next steps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your expansion; You are missing `R`.

```
(p<->q) ^ (q<->r)
```

Expanding the implications:

```
((p^~q) v (~p^q)) ^ ((q^~r) v (~q^r))
```

Distributing `((p^~q) v (~p^q))^` over the right side:

```
((p^~q) v (~p^q))^(q^~r) v ((p^~q) v (~p^q))^(~q^r)
```

Distributing `^(q^~r)` and `^(~q^r)` over their respective left sides:

```
(p^~q)^(q^~r) v (~p^q)^(q^~r) v (p^~q)^(~q^r) v (~p^q)^(~q^r)
```

From here you can simplify it easily.